# How to properly write unicode words to image using PHP imgttftext() function

Tags: php, image, unicode

I am trying to write some Urdu text on an image using imgttftext() function of PHP. It does not display the characters unless I convert the text using the following code:

```
function convert($text){
    $out="";
    mb_language('uni');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES',"UTF-8");
    $text = html_entity_decode($text,ENT_NOQUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
        $letter = $text[$i];
        $num = ord($letter);
        if($num>127) {
              $out .= "&#$num;";
        } else {
              $out .=  $letter;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Now, the text e.g. عچں (which contains the three characters ع چ ں) is printed on to the image as separate and full characters instead of cutting and joining the characters to form an Urdu word like عچں.

I have used the characters ا ب ت ث  with codes U+0627,  U+0628, U+0629 and so on from this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Arabic

I have shared the code here: https://code.google.com/p/urdu-captcha/downloads/list

> Note: I have added space between the characters in the code provided
>   removing which makes no difference to how the text is displayed on the
>   image.

How do I make it write the characters joined together to form proper words?

Comment: can you add more of your code, e.g. which font are you using, how large is your image? In which charset is your text when you pass it to the convert function?

Comment: and: did you check that you don't have a problem as Urdu is rtf? There is an example in the [imgttftext manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagettftext.php#97767)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion for rtf. I am editing the question to add some more code and information.

Comment: I have tried other TTF fonts in your code (which by the way could be much more straightford in handling UTF-8 encoded strings), and they are all rendered without glyph joining. It appears to be a serious shortcoming of `imagettftext()`

Comment: @RaoufAthar how you solved it , b/c its not working for me 'm using JameelNooriNastaleeq.ttf font for this .

Comment: Aaah, that was long time ago. I think I used AR-PHP as mentioned in the accepted answer below. If I remember properly, all fonts don't work with it. I will try to see if I can get my hands on that old code and let you know which fonts I used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need an additional library to perform Arabic glyph joining. Check out [AR-PHP](http://ar-php.org/Glyphs-example-php-arabic.html).

Comment: +1, because from my tests this appears the best way to overcome the shortcomings of `imagettftext()`

Comment: Just a note about the example code of [`Ar-PHP`](http://ar-php.org/Glyphs-example-php-arabic.html): the `$text` variable is reused to hold the transformed text, which is only good as input for `imagettftext()`. In order to avoid confusion a different variable should have been used.

Comment: Arabic.php not working fine for all words. Please let me know if you know how to get this fixes.

Comment: `$text2 = 'ملتان پاکستان';`
`$text2 = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text2);`
`imagettftext($jpg_image, 100, 0, 500, 950, $white, $font_b, $text2);`
This is the code i'm using but its breaking at Pay and Kaaf